Why does the margin difference occur when \arrow is placed in curly brackets?

X \leftarrow Y {\leftarrow} Z: 
X \mapsto Y {\mapsto} Z: 

Why is there such a difference? Which one is more recommended?

compare $a+b$ and $a{+}b$  the brace group makes the symbols lose their relation or binary infix spacing and just act as a normal mathord symbol. Only use the braces if you intend the non standard interpretation.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Space in math mode depends on the class of the character ("mathord", "mathop", "mathbin", "mathrel", "mathopen", "mathclose", and "mathpunct"). See this question for more details. \leftarrow and \mapsto are math relation. X \leftarrow Y gives the correct spacing ("mathrel"), not X {\leftarrow} Y.
